# Calculate the standard proportion of the image height with fixed image width in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, image, height

I have taken the image from the iPhone 4G and post those images to the server, after that i fetched those images and displayed in the table view cell. I want to display the correct aspect ratio of the image, when change the image height.

In my calculation,

```
  CGSize imageSize = image.size;

 CGFloat imageWidth = imageSize.width; (620) (In retina from iPhone 4G)

 CGFloat imageHeight = imageSize.height; (620)  (In retina from iPhone 4G)

 CGFloat aspectRatio = imageSize.width / imageSize.height; (620 / 620 = 1).

 CGFloat newImageWidth = 300.0f; (Fixed Width). 

 // Calculate new Image Height.

CGFloat newImageHeight = newImageWidth / aspectRatio; (300 / 1 = 300)

So, new image width / height.(300, 300).
```

And, Should i need to check the image is retina or not?

I don't know, whether the calculation is correct or not, so please guide me to achieve this.
I want to know, standard procedure to find the height of the image with the fixed image width(Set the correct aspect ratio).

Please help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: I think your calculation is correct, you may need to multiply your image size with `image.scale` (returns 2.0 on @2x image) if you really want a real size of an image.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put it into a `UIImageView` and set its `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`?

Comment: i have already set the UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit. But my requirement is, image set it to the image view exact width and standard proportion height. So i want to know, how to calculate standard proportion of image height depends on the fixed image width. Thanks.