# find proportional height of UIImage from fixed width in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage

Hello my question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613443/calculate-the-standard-proportion-of-the-image-height-with-fixed-image-width-in)

I am arranging images in a grid manner. this grid has three columns, every column has fixed width of 100px and i want to scale UIImage with this width.

For better explanation i have attached an image

[image]

As shown in image i want to find the height.

Comment: `height = 100 / original_width * original_height`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you, if possible, use [`PSCollectionView`](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pscollectionview) for this type of display.